# c# Regular expression pattern to find digit

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I'm trying to make a correct regular expression pattern to find me the digit **4** when before **and/or** after it has letters `a-z` and digits `4` and `6`(and only the first letter could be capital `A-Z`, **if exist**). But not when it's only with numbers, even if they are 4 and 6! If I find `4` I want to raplace it with `ч` other symbols stay the same!

Example:

> abs4 4ao 4epa4 a46 E4a 4e ne4es6 (All True)
>
> 4 a41 4a7 456 **46**  **64**  **44**   **e4A**   (All False)

This code almost work

`string replaced4 = Regex.Replace(richTextBox3.Text, "([A-Z]?[a-z]+)4([a-z46])|([A-Z]?[a-z46])4([a-z]+)", "$1ч$2");`

There are two exceptions when this code doesn't work.

1. If 4 is first symbol

2. If 4 is last symbol

And the problem is here `"$1ч$2"` but I don't know hot to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is the first example all true? By your definition--["between"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between)--only the last one can be true...

Answer (score 0):

Manually check that it has a 4 in it (`myString.Contains('4')`), then use this:

```
[A-Za-z46][a-z46]+
```

---

```
if (RegEx.IsMatch(myString, "[A-Za-z46][a-z46]+"))
{
  myString = myString.Replace("4", "$1ч$2"); // If there's not actually a 4, it won't do anything.
}
```

Comment: @NqkoiSi - I misread the examples to always be 3 characters.  Just edited.

Comment: I'm new in C# and I don't know how to make the replacement with your code. I mean, I use "$1ч$2" but with your code I don't know how to do it.

string replaced4 = Regex.Replace(richTextBox3.Text, "([A-Za-z]*^[01235789])4([a-z*)^[01235789]", "$1ч$2");

Comment: Do you want it to only replace the 4, or the whole group?

Comment: only 4 the others are the same.

Comment: Give this version a try.  It'll only work if you're looking at each grouping one-by-one, though.

Comment: Doesn't work.

If input is  "456 is" OK
but if it's "ae 456"  wrong!